# How to change the position of a imageButton when onClick

Tags: android, user-interface

I am trying to shift the position of a image button when on click. I tried the following but it crashes at "rlOut.addView(imgP, p);" I have no issues when running them in onCreate().

public class Delet3Activity extends Activity {

```
RelativeLayout rlOut;
ImageButton imbBtn;

EditText et1, et2;
ImageView ivB;
ImageButton imgP;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

int mX, mY;
```

@Override

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);

imbBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
rlOut = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlOut);
imgP = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgP);

ivB = new ImageView(this);
ivB.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

width = width/2-62;
height = height/2-62;
p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(62, 62);    

imbBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {



    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams)imbBtn.getLayoutParams();

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            Log.d("ok","down");
            mX = (int) event.getX() - imbBtn.getWidth() / 2;
            mY = (int) event.getY() - imbBtn.getHeight() / 2;
            et1.setText("mX down: "+String.valueOf(mX));
            et2.setText("mY down: "+String.valueOf(mY));


        }
        else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            Log.d("ok","up");
            rlOut.addView(ivB, params);
            p.leftMargin=4;
            params.leftMargin = 60;
            params.topMargin = 20;
            rlOut.addView(imgP, p);
            Log.d("ok","p");
        }
        else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            Log.d("ok","move");
            mX = (int) event.getX() - imbBtn.getWidth() / 2;
            mY = (int) event.getY() - imbBtn.getHeight() / 2;
            et1.setText("mX move: "+String.valueOf(mX));
            et2.setText("mY move: "+String.valueOf(mY));
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

}
}

Comment: You have to inflate the view before using it . Use something like layout inflater.

Comment: What error is shown in logcat when your app crashes and where exactly have you declared the view variable `rlOut`?

Comment: The msg is: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578) warning msg
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: I declared rlOut inside the class before the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

`OnCreate` method is the place where you set the `setContentView(R.layout.main)`. I suppose the variable `rlOut` stands for `RelativeLayout` which might be in your main layout. Call the above function within the OnCreate methods after you set the contentView and have **initialized** the variable `rlOut` using `findViewById`. Or if the variable `rlOut` is in some other layout file then you will have to first inflate that layout using layout inflater and then find the view using  `findViewById` method.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

The following code should probably be the solution you are looking for:

```
imbBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams)imbBtn.getLayoutParams();

            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                Log.d("ok","move");
                mX = (int) event.getX() - imbBtn.getWidth() / 2;
                mY = (int) event.getY() - imbBtn.getHeight() / 2;
                par.leftMargin = imbBtn.getLeft() + mX;
                par.topMargin = imbBtn.getTop() + mY;
                imbBtn.setLayoutParams(par);
                et1.setText("mX move: "+String.valueOf(mX));
                et2.setText("mY move: "+String.valueOf(mY));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` is the only event you need to capture. Hope this solution is helpful to you.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt state clearly, rlOut is RelativeLayout. I have no idea what is layout inflater, what is it for and how to use it. I will go and find it out then.

Comment: I can paste the entire code for layout inflation but if you search/find it out yourself you can learn that concept in its entirety. Do comeback if you have any doubt.

Comment: I still do not understand when should I use the layer inflater, when onClick? In addition, I do not see how I can change the imageButton position after or before the layer inflater.

Comment: Ok. Paste the entire code and I'll tell you where exactly you are going wrong.

Comment: I pasted what I am trying to do, for the layer inflater I tried on another file which is not shown in the code. it is a bit messy since I am trying on both onTouch() and the onCreate. Basically what I am trying to implement now is to allow user to press on the button and  the button will follow the finger that pressed on the screen and when the user lift up the finger, the button position will be change to the position that the user finger lift up from.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try the edited code I pasted above? If yes, were you able to solve your problem?